FFT to compute a Bode diagram to find resonance in MATLAB
I am trying to create a MATLAB code that takes input and output signals from an Excel file. In the first column of the file, there is the time at which the data was acquired, in the second column are the amplitude response data. In the third column, there are the time instants of the input, and in the fourth column, the amplitudes provided as input. Since the output data is generated by another software, there are fewer output data points than input data points. My goal, as stated in the subject, is to create a MATLAB code that can generate a Bode plot to find the resonance frequency.
I have tried using spline interpolation to increase the number of output points, and then I perform the FFT on both to find the gain. Additionally, I have tried using the MATLAB function pwelch, but I did not obtain acceptable results in terms of noise and peaks. I think I might be doing something wrong. Below is my code. I expect a resonance frequency between 140 and 250 Hz, and I expect there not to be all that noise.
clear 
close all
clc
%% Excel
files = dir('*.xlsx');
t0 = 2;
figure;
for i = 1:length(files)
    x_out = [];
    x_in = [];
    t_out = [];
    t_in = [];
    raw = readtable(files(i).name);
    %% Definition of Input
    t = linspace(0, 0.36, 1024);
    freq = str2num(extractBefore(files(i).name, '.xlsx'));
    t_in = t;
    x_in = sin(freq * 2 * pi * t);
    x_in = spline(t_in, x_in, t);
    
    %% Definition of Output
    t_out = raw{:, 1} - t0; % From 0-0.36s 
    x_out = raw{:, 4};
    t_out = t_out(~isnan(t_out));
    x_out = x_out(~isnan(t_out)) / 9810; %Conversion from mm to units of gravity
    
    %% Interpolation
    x_out_interp = spline(t_out, x_out, t_in);
    
    %% Pwelch
    window = hanning(256);
    noverlap = round(length(window) * 0.66); % 66% overlap
    Fs_in = 1 / (mean(diff(t_in)));
    Fs_out = 1 / (mean(diff(t_out)));
    [pxx_in, f_in] = pwelch(x_in, window, noverlap, [], Fs_in);
    [pxx_out, f_out] = pwelch(x_out_interp, window, noverlap, [], Fs_out);
    
    %% Plot PSDs
    figure(2)
    subplot(2, 1, 1)
    hold on
    plot(f_in, 10 * log10(pxx_in), DisplayName=files(i).name)
    title('Power Spectral Density of Input Signal')
    xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    ylabel('Power/Frequency [dB/Hz]')
    grid on
    legend("show")

    subplot(2, 1, 2)
    hold on
    plot(f_out, 10 * log10(pxx_out), DisplayName=files(i).name)
    title('Power Spectral Density of Interpolated Output Signal')
    xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    ylabel('Power/Frequency [dB/Hz]')
    grid on
    legend("show")
    
    %% Gain
    gain = 10 * log10(abs(pxx_out) ./ abs(pxx_in));
    
    %% Plot Bode
    figure(3)
    hold on
    semilogx(f_in, gain, DisplayName=files(i).name)
    title('Bode Plot - Gain')
    xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    ylabel('Gain [dB]')
    grid on
    xlim([0 1000])
    legend("show")
end

Input:

Output:

The input can also be generated in MATLAB without being extracted from an Excel file, as long as it has an amplitude of 1 and a frequency of 140 Hz. The time duration is equal to 0.36s
Excel file open
In this Excel file, the results derived from the FEM analysis are contained (1st column: time [s], 2nd column: amplitude, which should be divided by 9810 to convert it into gravity units), and it is configured as the output for the Bode diagram. The sinusoidal input for plotting the Bode diagram is generated by the MATLAB code.

Please attach the Excel input file, or a portion of such file. Readers should be able to reproduce the question. Without the Excel file you describe in the question, or part of it, there's no way to reproduce your question.

You're right; I apologize for the inconvenience. I have uploaded the Excel file.

The link to access the Excel file is now working.
